# JQuery UI: Drag & Drop revert issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have 2 elements (draggables) and 2 droppable areas.

Whenever I drag an element into an area, I set the 'accept' of the drop area to the id of the element that was dropped to prevent other elements from being dropped. However, I try to revert other elements that attempt to enter the previously entered area but it's not really working the way I want.

The thing is, I managed to revert the other element but whenever I try to drag that second element to the second empty droppable area, it reverts back to its position.

Any suggestion on how to approach that problem?

Thank you

UPDATE:

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GRDww/243/

```
var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
var box2 = document.getElementById('box2');
var drop1 = document.getElementById('drop1');
var drop2 = document.getElementById('drop2');

$(box1).draggable({
    snap: '.drop1.drop2'
})

$(box2).draggable({
    snap: '.drop1.drop2'
})

$(drop1).droppable({
    drop: function(event,ui){
   alert('dropped')
  }
})

$(drop2).droppable({
    drop: function(event,ui){
   alert('dropped')
  }
})
```

Comment: You are better to post your code here.

Comment: Updated the post! :)